# Convert to application in IIS under service account

Tags: asp.net, iis, user-accounts

I want convert to application my Asp.Net app. 
I created application Pool what use service account. And want "convert to application" under this application pool.

BUT if i check connection setting show me error "Invalid application path".

When I set my personal user account in to "connect as" 
everything was alright.

Question : what must fulfill service account to right use? Or any suggestion whot I must change, try or verify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the Setting "ApplicationPoolIdentity" for Identity in the Pool Advanced-Properties.

Usually your folder security settings must grant read, execute, browse folder and read for the local group IIS_IUSRS.

if you did both, the conversion to application should work.